# What is spray latex paint?

Tags: paint, asbestos

An abatement professional suggested that we use spray latex paint to coat a pipe that has embedded asbestos fibers.

I can't find anything online or at stores that is labeled latex spray paint.

Comment: We'll need some more information (e.g. what's "InUse spray latex paint"?)

Comment: Sorry...iPhone typing mistake!

Comment: I think they're trying to tell you to coat the fiber without dragging paint brushes or rollers through it.

Answer (score 2):

Many professional painters use a compressor and a paint gun to paint (usually) common latex paints in homes and apartments.

Here's a couple videos about [professional sprayers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTsvG8yepJw) and another about [residential sprayers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vNzfjxXjYg).

Comment: They mentioned that I can get it in a can. Any ideas which brands and/or words on the can that would indicate latex paint? I didn't find the words "latex" in any cans at the big box store.

Comment: @milesmeow - Spray paint is generally acrylic. Your only concern (afaik) would be adhesion to the undercoat, but I don't think you'll have any problems no matter what type of spray paint you get (as long as you're not trying to coat latex with some oil-base, which you can't really get anymore, so...)

Comment: In this article(https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiR_uvJ6NbNAhXB6oMKHamkBXwQFghSMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.doityourself.com%2Fstry%2Fhow-to-seal-asbestos-ceiling-tiles&usg=AFQjCNFLMhd6UQZncjaZHca2bcPKXuQ2ag) it recommends an "airless sprayer"...the residential sprayer link you sent is an airless sprayre.  Thanks!